# Download any file using windows form application with c#

Tags: c#

I'll try to download file using this code.But file size is 0 KB.What is the correct and efficiency way to download the file.

```
private void DownloadFile()
{
    using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
    {
        Client.DownloadFileAsync(
            new Uri("http://localhost/sn/userSelect.Designer.cs", UriKind.Absolute),
            @"C:\xampp\htdocs\sn\test1.txt");
        Client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Any one can give me the method for download the file over windows form program in C#.thanks

Comment: Did you read the [documentation for `DownloadFileAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144196.aspx)?

Comment: In particular, what do you believe the "async" part means?

Comment: I'll used both method such as **DownloadFileAsync** and **DownloadFile** .but same result. :(

Comment: @Elshan - why dispose a class that is doing a async work?

Comment: @AppDeveloper I'm try to each and every method to get the result that's the reason(but it want)....

Comment: can u show more of your code, and one thing, r u trying the DownloadFileAsync in main() method?

Comment: Google "C# DownloadFileAsync example" for copy-pastable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Program
{
    private static WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    private static ManualResetEvent handle = new ManualResetEvent(true);
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += WcOnDownloadProgressChanged;
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += WcOnDownloadFileCompleted;
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(@"http://www.nattyware.com/bin/pixie.exe"), @"C:\\pixie.exe");
        handle.WaitOne(); // wait for the async event to complete

    }

    private static void WcOnDownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
        {
            //async download completed successfully
        }
        handle.Set(); // in both the case let the void main() know that async event had finished so that i can quit
    }

    private static void WcOnDownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // handle the progres in case of async
        //e.ProgressPercentage
    }
```